# Java message digest update converted in PHP

Tags: java, php

I have this code in Java [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Z08w46ut). Sorry for pastebin link but SO doesn't allow me to paste that much code

Which outputs "Ap1pAXP8yS"

I'm trying to convert the code in PHP. Till now I have converted some but its not working OK ( not getting Ap1pAXP8yS in PHP ).

The main problem seems to be the md.update

Here the code in PHP

```
function bin2print($hex)
{
    $out = "";
    $mapping = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '$', 'j', 'k', '-', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '=', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '.', '/', '%' ];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($hex); $i++) {
    
        $j = $hex[$i];
        
        if ($j < 0) {
            $j = 256 + $j;
        }

        $out.=  $mapping [($j % count($mapping)) ];
    }
    return $out;
}

function byteStr2byteArray($s)
{
    return array_slice(unpack("C*", "\0".$s), 1);
} 
 
 
function getBytes($string)
{
 
    $bytes = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $bytes[] = ord($string[$i]);
    }

    $out = '';
    foreach($bytes as $single) {
        $out.=$single ;
    }
    return ($out);
}
 
$serial = '111111111111';
$header = 'cow';

$ctx = hash_init('md5' );
hash_update($ctx, getBytes($header));
hash_update($ctx, getBytes($serial));
$raw = hash_final($ctx,true);

$out = bin2print(byteStr2byteArray($raw));

echo substr($out,0,10);
```

Which outputs "-fjk7WCU2E"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bugs, but most of all you're just overcomplicating things. Simply use base64 encoding and built-in functions. On PHP side:

```
$ctx = hash_init('md5');
hash_update($ctx, $header);
hash_update($ctx, $serial);
$raw = hash_final($ctx, true);
$out = substr(base64_encode($raw), 0, 10);
```

On Java side:

```
// ...
raw = md.digest();
out = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(raw).substring(0, 10);
```